# How to disable checking C header names in Flyspell?

Tags: emacs, elisp, flyspell

In Emacs when flyspell-prog-mode is active, C/C++ header names are also checked by Flyspell. So the spell checker complains of stdlib.h, stdio.h, but is ok with something like string.h.

Does anyone know how to fix this annoying Flyspell behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour seems fixed in newer versions of Emacs (tested with 24.4 and 25.3).

Old response, confused the two flyspell modes:

<s>Perhaps use `flyspell-prog-mode` instead of `flyspell-mode`? This restricts flyspell to strings and comments, however, so it will not correct misspelled variable or function names.</s>

Comment: At the time I asked this question, flyspell-prog-mode behave like I described in the original post (I explicitly mentioned flyspell-prog-mode).

Comment: You're right, it seems I misread that. It should be fixed with newer versions of flyspell, however.